# How to exclude sub folders while reading files from Azure storage using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to read json files from Azure storage recursively from the sub-directories using python.

Below is the folder structure.

```
mainfolder
| - subfolder1
| | -file1.json
| | -file2.json
| | -file3.json
| | -file4.json
| - subfolder2
| | - file1.json
| | - file2.json
| | - file3.json
```

I want to read only the files under `subfolder1` and `subfolder2` into a dataframe.
I am using the below code.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from pandas import DataFrame
connect_str = ""
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name="raw"
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="mainfolder")

for blob in blob_list:
    #print("\t" + blob.name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    streamdownloader = blob_client.download_blob()
    fileReader = json.loads(streamdownloader.readall())
    df = pd.DataFrame(fileReader)
    print(df.to_string())
```

The above code is not working, since the client.list_blobs is also listing the sub-directories `(subfolder1,subfolder2)`.
Is there any way to exclude the subfolders, list and read only the files from the mainfolder.

Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind: there are no "folders" - just containers. Anything looking like a subfolder under a container... is just a part of the filename. So you can filter on name prefix, but you are still going to enumerate all content in the container. For actual folder support, look into ADLS (storage with hierarchical directory support)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify that there are no folders in the Blob Storage the files inside Blob Storage are called blobs and the virtual folders inside it are called directories. Below is the hierarchy that you can observe in blob storage.

Blob Storage > Containers > Directories/Virtual Folders > Blobs

To view only subfolder1 and subfolder2 and not the directories inside it one of the workarounds is to use "prefix". Below is the code that was working for me.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<ACCOUNT_NAME>"
CONTAINER_NAME = "<CONTAINER_NAME>"
SAS_TOKEN='<SAS_TOKEN>'

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=None,sas_token=SAS_TOKEN)

print("\nList blobs in the Subfolder1 and Subfolder2")
generator = blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME,prefix="subfolder")
for blob in generator:
    blobname=blob.name
    print(blobname)
```

[image]

Below is the hierarchy inside my blob storage

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried the prefix using  BlobServiceClient. However,it gives me all the files in the container instead of giving the files in the folder mentioned in the prefix.

Comment: I cant use BlockBlobService as the azurestorageblob version is 2.12 which is not compatible with my other Azure functions(12.0+ version)